# ZigBee integration (IP/Gateway)

Tags: protocols, zigbee

I am looking into a way of integrating with ZigBee via LAN. Basically, what I want to achieve, is to

- be able to control dimmers (read/write value)
- get events from presence detection (events)
- control other devices, such as blinds/shades

The ZigBee standard defines a gateway (ZGD), with REST/SOAP/GRIP protocols (where GRIP is a favourite). All though this seems to solve what I'm looking for, finding devices that supports this seems to be diffcult.

I'm looking to buy an appropriate gateway rather than building one.

Answer (score 6):

[Ubisys G1](http://www.ubisys.de/en/smarthome/products-g1.html) seems to be a device (the only one?) that does this.

A brief description from the product page, for reference:

> Our gateway links your ubisys smart home to the outside world. It establishes a link via the internet connecting the ubisys smart home App on your mobile end device with the ubisys smart home components installed in your home. Connect the gateway with your DSL, UMTS or LTE router and you can manage and monitor your home while on the road. Due to the gateway being permanently active we designed it to be very economical: Less than a single Watt is required while in use.